# How do I run a Linux application in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, wine

I need to run a Linux application under Windows. Is there an application like [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) (which runs Windows applications under Linux) that will do the job?

Comment: What linux application do you want to run under Windows?

Comment: If you're running a 32-bit version of Windows, [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/) might work. It really depends on what your specific application is; even WINE can only run *some*, not all, Windows applications on Linux.

Comment: It would help to say what application, some might have ports, or be easily portable.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I want to run application compiled from my own source code under linux.

Comment: CLI or GUI? If its GUI, does it use a toolkit thats portable?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: CLI, only 64bit standard library used, and the windows box is 64bit too.

Comment: Then I would just recompile with mingw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't run Linux applications directly under Windows as [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) does with Windows applications on Linux, but you do have a couple of options:

1. You can use a virtualization solution such as [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/) to run a complete Linux operating system inside your Windows machine. This is probably your best option for running Linux binaries.
2. You can use a Unix-like environment like [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to provide a basic Unix command set, compiler etc. If you have source code for your Linux program, you can use cygwin to compile it under Windows.

Comment: try Mobaxterm, no need to install, fully portable. ssh into your linux box and run the program.